# User,Admin and super-Admin custom django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a models in django where there are users, administrators responsible for multiple users and finally a super-admin responsible for the all users and admin. So I wonder what is the best way for create this models?
I would also like each user to have a relationship one-to-one with the User of django.I also need managers and the super admin has an associated user. Everyone should be able to log, which is why I need that everyone has associated a normal user. Thus if an administrator or wish to change the super admin as administrator should only click a button on the main page for the redirect to the admin console. Maybe inheritances are useful here but nose as if after Hare implement a relationship between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's user permission system can take care of everything you need on it's own. With the addition of a 3rd party library like [`django-permissions`](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-permission) or [`django-authority`](https://github.com/jlward/django-authority) (which touts per-object permissions) you can get very particular about user controls.

In short, when you log in to the Django admin with a superuser account, go to `Authentication and Authorization -> Groups`. From there, you'll see that per app in your project there are **add**, **edit**, and **delete** permissions; these tie in to the admin per user. To use these permissions or custom page permissions in your project, you can use [permissions decorators or functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions). You can add more groups, customize group permissions, add page-level permissions, etc. User's can belong to multiple groups and user-level permissions can override group permissions.

While there's a lot to explore and set up for what you like, it's both completely within the realm of Django and easily done without inheritance or hard coding each of these permissions within your user model.

Comment: Whenever I went to the administrator console saw the section 'group' but never find out what it was Thanks.